# Sql search statement always returning empty even when there is data in database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using the following to fetch a string from my table. The cursor is always returning empty even when I have data in database. Is the query wrong?

```
public void find(String myNumber){
 String[] thecolumns = new String[]{
            ID,
            FLAG};

cursor = sqlDb.query(MY_TABLE,
            thecolumns, NUMBER + "='"
                    + myNumber+ "'", null, null, null, null);

 if (cursorToFetchAssets != null   ) {

        cursorToFetchAssets.moveToFirst();{
        try{
            //code to fetch

         }catch{
         //return when there are no rows found. 

     }
 }
```

EDIT: NUMBER is of type string  "...+ NUMBER  + " TEXT,.. " and myNumber is also a string

Comment: Please update your code with proper syntax, logic, and formatting

Comment: Is `myNumber` a number or a string?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: Issue was on the server side of my code. Not over here..

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
cursor = sqlDb.query(
        MY_TABLE,
        thecolumns, 
        NUMBER + "=?", 
        new String[]{String.valueOf(number)}, 
        null, null, null);
```